# Linkedin API request

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I have simple script to get data from LINKEDin, it works fine, only problem I see is in way of getting data.  It looks as:

```
$xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,num-connections,educations,date-of-birth)");
```

If I `echo $xml_response` I get to data. Problem is that `$xml_respose` is basicly one long string. And I'm not sure HOW to work with this.

Let's imagine situation I have simple table where I want to insert things. It should looks like one below. How can I access to each value (without creating multiple linkedin request). I mean is there a way how to write this request to be able get value with object: `$request->first-name`  or array:  `$request['first-name']` ?

```
| Name  |  Last Name | HeadLine | Num-Connections |
----------------------------------------------------
| myName| mySurname  | myHeadline|  myConnections |
```

Comment: you can parse XML and write such code that will give you first name by `$request['first-name']`

Comment: What PHP library do you use for the LinkedIn API?

Comment: can you please show what type of data you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `format=json` URL argument to the end of your API call, and then format as json (using php `json_decode` function)